# I can not see my mouse when I use QEMU to open a Windows XP guest in an Ubuntu guest created by virtualbox on my MAC computer

Tags: windows, qemu

First on my MAC(OSX), I use virtualbox to create an Ubuntu guest. Then in Ubuntu, I use root to create a Windows XP guest using command:

```
./qemy-system-i386 -monitor stdio -m 512 -netdev user,id=mynet -device rtl8139,netdev=mynet <Windows Image file>
```

But after I got into Windows, I nearly can not see my mouse！ However, in the QEMU window, I have seen "QEMU Press Ctl-Alt to exit mouse grab", so it looks like it should have already grabbed the mouse correctly. But I can not see it.

Comment: Um, this is not a programming question. It belongs on superuser.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found the answer on my own. The solution is to disable mouse integration in VirtualBox:>